# Forward declaration of class in header causes incomplete type

Tags: c++, header, incomplete-type

I had a look at [forward declaring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4757565/c-forward-declaration) to get around the compile error " error: variable or field ‘mov_avg’ declared void".
 Following scenario: There is one data_proc.cpp having the main() including a custom header `my_mov_avg.h`, which embeds the function `mov_avg(shared)`.  Furthermore the header function accesses `class cl_shared` inside the main-file. The files look like:

```
#include <string.h>     //c++ headers
#include <iostream> //red?

#include "my_mov_avg.h" //outsourced function

using namespace std;

/* class accessed from header*/
class cl_shared {
public:
    //constructor 
    cl_shared() { };

    int getint() {
        return a;
    }
private:
    int a;
};
cl_shared shared; //class object

/*main calling function inside header*/
int main(int argc, char **argv){
    mov_avg(shared);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

The header `my_mov_avg.h` file:

```
//in .h
void say();
void mov_avg();

//in .cpp
#include <string.h>     
#include <iostream> 
#include "my_mov_avg.h"


void say() {
    std::cout << "Ohai from another .cpp file!";
}
class cl_shared; //Forward declaration
void mov_avg(cl_shared shared){
        std::cout<<" int from class: "<< shared.getint()<< std::endl; 
}
```

Now as I forward declared so that the function argument type is defined I got this compile error:

```
 error: ‘shared’ has incomplete type
 void mov_avg(cl_shared shared){
      ^
 /my_mov_avg.cpp:9:11: error: forward declaration of ‘class cl_shared’
 class cl_shared;
       ^
```

How to get it to compile and is it bad design to access the class cl_shared from the header?
 What I try to achieve is to repeatedly access data (here broken down to a changing int) from where the header-function was called. 
 I could break out the `class cl_shared` into a separate header file and include it in both but I'm not sure, additionally it causes another header file(which might not be necessary).
**EDIT** added argument inside the my_mov_avg.h 
 `void mov_avg(cl_shared shared);` but still causes:

```
my_mov_avg.h:3:14: error: variable or field ‘mov_avg’ declared void
 void mov_avg(cl_shared shared);
```

sidenote: a quick and dirty hack to break down one big cpp-file is to place the function into a seperate cpp and place `#include "seperate.cpp"` where the function originally was. Use only with simple programs.

Comment: First off, your forward declaration of mov_avg() contains no parameters, your definition does. Next up, you can not forward declare classes and use them directly, the compiler needs the definition in your .cpp, so you need to hoist the definition of cl_shared into a separate header that your main and my_mov_avg.cpp file uses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forward declarations only work if you use the class as a pointer / reference and do not attempt to access any of its members. When you pass by value the compiler needs to know the exact size .etc. of the type and therefore needs the full class declaration.

```
void mov_avg(cl_shared shared){
```

Here you are passing by value (that is you are passing a copy of shared on the stack) therefore the compiler needs the full class declaration. Also as you access members of the class, switching to pass by pointer/reference will not be enough as the compiler will need to know the memory layout of class members.

You need to declare cl_shared somewhere my_mov_arg.h can access it prior to using it.

On a sidetone when you declare non-class member functions in a header i.e. like mov_arg, you should declare them as inline. Otherwise the function definition will be added to every source file you use the header in and cause compilation errors.

EDIT. This should do it. You can also move the member functions from cl_shared.h into a cl_shared.cpp file if you want. The *#pragma once* at the top of the header files are to ensure the header only gets included once per compilation unit:

cl_shared.h:

```
#pragma once

class cl_shared {
    public:
    //constructor 
    cl_shared() { };

    int getint() {
        return a;
    }
private:
    int a;
};
```

my_mov_avg.h

```
#pragma once
#include "cl_shared.h"

void say();
void mov_avg(cl_shared shared);
```

Comment: So I need to make another header having the class declaration? Also you suggest to put the function out of the header back into the cpp file. (Thats  where I started. I want to break down the main file )

Comment: If there is no need to put them in seperate header files, you can also put them in the same header file.

Answer (score 0):

If the header file only has

```
void mov_avg();
```

Then this would be a different function - one that takes no arguments. C++ strongly types functions - overloads can have different argument signatures but the same name. So it has seen a declaration of `move_avg()` but not one of `move_avg(cl_shared shared)`.